# Mechanics Impulse Find mass of the bullet

Tags: classical-mechanics

A marksman fires a bullet from a gun with a horizontal speed of $360ms^{-1})$
The mass of the gun is $3kg$.

The gun recoils into the marksman's shoulder with a horizontal speed of $6ms^{-1}$.

Find the mass of the bullet.

The gun comes to rest after $1/18$ seconds.

I get lost attempting this question and don't understand what method to use.

Comment: Use conservation of momentum

Comment: $6 \mathrm m \mathrm s^{-2}$ is not a speed, it's an acceleration. I guess in the original statement of this question, that is the acceleration that occurs to the gun as it pushes against the marksman's shoulder.

Comment: Is it as simple as $360 * m = 6 *3$
$m=18/36$
$m=0.5$

Comment: Edited speed, there was incorrect units. It should be $ms^{-1}$, it should now be corrected.

Comment: That's starting to sound reasonable, just be careful with the decimal point (and the number of digits); I don't think the bullet is supposed to weigh 500 grams. If the new problem statement is correct then the $1/18$ seconds is just a red herring.

Comment: I've just realised my mistake, it should be 
$360∗m=6∗3m$ So $m=18/36 = 0.05$ , 50g grams sounds more reasonable for the mass of the bullet.